# Flink on AWS EMR Task Nodes

Tags: apache-flink, amazon-emr, flink-streaming

Is it possible to run Flink task managers on the Task nodes of AWS EMR? If yes, how different is it from running Task Managers on a core node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to run TMs on task nodes. The only difference I'd expect is that EMR won't schedule the Flink Job Manager (JM) on a task node ("Amazon EMR ... allows application master processes to run only on core nodes").

If your workflow has sources that read from HDFS and/or sinks that write to HDFS, then subtasks of these operators running on task nodes *might* take longer, as task nodes don't run the Hadoop Data Node daemon, and thus all reads/writes are over the network.